# why do i get 404 the requested resources not found when i run php -S localhost:8888

Tags: php, apache, localhost, http-status-code-404

why do I get 404 the requested resources not found when I run php -S localhost:8888 .
it used to work before and after I deleted a certain project(laravel project) this error started to come. how can I slove this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your are in the folder `/project`, and you run `php -S localhost:8888`in it. If then you request for example `localhost:8888/index.php`, the file `index.php` has to be in the `/project` folder, where you run the `php -S localhost:8888` command.

If the file `index.php` is instead in the folder `/project/src`, then you would run `php -S localhost:8888` in the `/project/src` folder instead of just `/project`.